# getting column count per work sheet Excell Library

Tags: c#, excellibrary

I am using the ExcelLibrary package. Was wondering how to determine the amount of columns per work sheet?.

```
var workbook = Workbook.Load(fileToValidate);
foreach (var v in workbook.Worksheets)
{
     //coulmn count for each sheet

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var workbook = Workbook.Load(fileToValidate);
foreach (var v in workbook.Worksheets)
{
     //coulmn count for each sheet
     int count = v.Columns.Count();

}
```